# Set ChannelData for Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework

When i try to set the ChannelData on facebook i find that if I do not attach any Attachments then Facebook not show What I attached in the ChannelData. for example:

if i send this:

```
var channelData = new JObject();
var child = new JObject();

child.Add("content_type", "text");
child.Add("title", "Red");
child.Add("payload", "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_RED");

channelData.Add("quick_replies", new JArray(child));

var replyOrder = context.MakeMessage();
var attachments = CardFactoryFacebook.GetMainContactThumbnailCard(); 

replyOrder.Attachments.Add(attachments);
replyOrder.ChannelData = channelData;

await context.PostAsync(replyOrder);
```

So in this case we will see in the messenger the ThumbnailCard and Immediately below the button I made in the ChannelData "Red".

But if I set the ChannelData without add any Attachments so Does not show anything in messenger e.g:

```
var replyOrder = context.MakeMessage();

replyOrder.ChannelData = channelData;

await context.PostAsync(replyOrder);
```

Am i missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to put a "activity" Attachment, everything should be defined on the channel data, (when it is about facebook and its cards), in this case there is a "facebook" attachment, but it is inside the channelData. I have this piece of code working:

```
 Activity replyToConversation = activity.CreateReply("Quick Replies");

                dynamic messageData = new JObject();
                messageData.attachment = new JObject();
                messageData.attachment.type = "template";
                messageData.attachment.payload = new JObject();
                messageData.attachment.payload.template_type = "generic";


                messageData.attachment.payload.elements
                    = new JArray(
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("title", "hola"),
                            new JProperty("subtitle", "Mundo"),
                            new JProperty("buttons",
                                new JArray(
                                    new JObject(
                                        new JProperty("type", "element_share")
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );


                replyToConversation.ChannelData = messageData;
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyToConversation);
```

Comment: works Thanks. i probably not created correctly the json format.

Answer (score 1):

[Quick Replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies) are being sent as part of a message. Based on Facebook's documentation, a message object must contain a text or an attachment to be valid.

[image: Quick Replies Doc]

With the channel data object that you created (which is well-formed) you are just sending the "quick_replies" portion of the message.

Try adding a text to your message, for example:

```
replyOrder.Text = "What's your favorite color?";
```

Please note that in the specific case of Quick Replies, the BotBuilder library already provides a way use them without having to manually create the ChannelData by using the [KeyboardCard](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d1/daa/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_connector_ex_1_1_keyboard_card.html). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230436/bot-framework-fails-to-send-facebookquickreply-using-addkeyboardcard-or-using-ch) for more information.

Comment: is it possible to add element_share as a quick reply for creating a share button

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Botframework API](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html) for Facebook messages, `Attachment` is where you put your Facebook message. Doesn't make much sense to send a message with no message.