# show all options using prompt.choice

Tags: botframework

I'm using PromptDialog.Choice to show options to user. The problem is :

I've 4 options but only 3 of them are showed. If user wants to see the last option, must use scroll. My bot is configured for messenger channel.

I've this :

```
           var dialog = new PromptDialog.PromptChoice<string>(options, "I can assist you with : ", "Sorry, that wans't a valid option", 2);
           context.Call(dialog, UserChose);
```

How to override PromptStyler to get this done ?

I want to show all the options to user when prompt is created without scroll.
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT after Ezequiel's comment:
If you use `PromptStyle.Keyboard`, you will automatically get a correct display as the QuickReply style is now supported by the framework:
[image: sample]

---

Initial answer:

If you are only using Facebook Messenger channel, you may use [Ezequiel Jadib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90081/ezequiel-jadib)'s Quick Replies implementation: https://github.com/ejadib/QuickReplies

It uses Facebook's ChannelData to set up real quick replies that Facebook Messenger displays in a good look-and-feel: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies

Samples:[image: examples]

You can read more info on this blog post: http://southworks.com/blog/2016/09/15/sending-facebooks-quick-replies-using-microsoft-bot-framework/

Comment: In fact, that was created before BotFramework has supports for QuickReplies. You should try to go with the official way of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230436/bot-framework-fails-to-send-facebookquickreply-using-addkeyboardcard-or-using-ch