# Issue with List of buttons in Microsoft Bot Builder for .NET - Channel: Facebook Messenger

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to add a list of buttons as inside a herocard. It works fine in Bot Emulator but doesn't work in Messenger Channel. Here's my code.

```
public static IList<Attachment> ToAttachmentList(this List<string> items)
{
        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        var actions = new List<CardAction>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            actions.Add(new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: item, value: item));
        }

        var heroCard = new HeroCard
        {
            Buttons = actions
        };

        attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());

        return attachments;
}

private async Task ShowOptions(IDialogContext context)
{
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();
        reply.Text = $"Here's what you can do.";
        reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
        reply.Attachments = Messages.OrderingOptions.ToAttachmentList();

        await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
```

[image: Output in Bot Emulator]

[image: Output in Messenger]

In Messenger, the last button gets added as a Carousel, all the button text is truncated.

Please help me fix this.

[image: In Messenger]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/postback-button), the button title has a 20 character limit.

Also, if you have more that 3 buttons, Facebook will split them as the [Button template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/button-template) expects from 1-3 buttons.

You will need to limit the characters to 20, so instead of *"I want to order pizza"*, you might want to use *"Order pizza"* for example. To add more buttons; you might want to explore [Quick Replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies) since the limit is 11 "buttons" (but you still have the 20 chars limit on the title). You can check this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230436/bot-framework-fails-to-send-facebookquickreply-using-addkeyboardcard-or-using-ch) to understand more about Quick Replies.

Comment: Is there any way to add 4 actions and also add the same sentence as text???

Comment: you need to limit the characters to 20, so instead of I want to order pizza, just use "Order pizza" for example. To add more buttons; you might want to explore Quick Replies (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies). The limit is 11 (but you still have the 20 chars limit on the title). You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230436/bot-framework-fails-to-send-facebookquickreply-using-addkeyboardcard-or-using-ch. Please upvote and set as answered

Comment: upvoting because there is no reason that this valid answer from @EzequielJadib got a negative score