# Bot Framework fails to send FacebookQuickReply ChannelData - How to find cause?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, facebook-messenger

In my bot application I was able to implement quick reply using the same method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230436/bot-framework-fails-to-send-facebookquickreply-using-addkeyboardcard-or-using-ch). Specifically:

```
var channelData = new FacebookChannelData();

channelData.QuickReplies = new[]
{
    new FacebookQuickReply(FacebookQuickReply.ContentTypes.Text, "Cathay", "Cathay"),
    new FacebookQuickReply(FacebookQuickReply.ContentTypes.Text, "HK Airlines", "Hong Kong Airlines"),
    new FacebookQuickReply(FacebookQuickReply.ContentTypes.Text, "HK Express", "HK Express")
};

reply.ChannelData = channelData;
```

...........

```
public class FacebookChannelData
{
    [JsonProperty("quick_replies")]
    public FacebookQuickReply[] QuickReplies { get; set; }
}
```

For 1 month I shutdown my bot in the cloud. When I redeployed it the quick replies does not work anymore. How do I find the cause?

My `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` version has been `3.8.0.0` ever since so I'm surprised the quick reply is not working. I already attached the debugger in my bot deployed to Azure and I did not get any exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the new [Suggested Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-suggested-actions). It is still a mystery to me why using the approach I put in my question suddenly stopped working even if I did not change `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` package. Also it would be great if there is a way to debug this type of error in the MS Bot Framework.